# How to login Gerrit as Administrator

Tags: git, gerrit

I installed my gerrit on Ubuntu server.

As gerrit said：The first people who logined gerrit is Administrator.

So I logined first with openID (google account),and I am the Administrator indeed.

But,when next day I relogin gerrit with my google account, I become a new register. The id is 100001(Administrator 's id is 100000),but both email are google's email,and are same.

What happened?

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is to temporarily disable authenticated logins.

Edit your [auth] statement in gerrit.config to look like this:

```
[auth]
type = development_become_any_account
```

And then force login as the admin, grant yourself access and then restore the [auth] config.

Keep in mind that anyone with access to your server during this time will also be able to be any account, so setup a firewall or something to narrow access down to just your workstation while you complete the above steps.

Comment: this is the best way, editing tables and hacking the database is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

gerrit automatically assign first login as administrator, and treat your google account as another id.

You can either

1. login with openid and add google account id into administrator group as well
2. manual change the database `system_config` for your google account.

see https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.12.2/access-control.html#administrators

Hope it gives hints.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and found Shawn Pearce's reply on the mailing list to be useful:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/repo-discuss/FkIPsL28OXM/OBJvKaMh-wgJ

HTH,

Answer (score 0):

So this is somewhat hairy, but because Gerrit stores its Group data in a [git repo](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-groups.html), albeit one with [unconventional refs](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/note-db.html), you can use [git plumbing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) commands to manually update it.

I hope you're comfortable with git plumbing!

This worked for me, with Gerrit 3.8.1 from Docker. I mounted my Gerrit `git` volume in another container that had Git.

1. Shut down Gerrit. (it seemed it flushed its internal Groups database otherwise, overwriting my prior changes)
2. find your Administrators group in the `All-Users.git` repo:

   1. List each group reference with `git for-each-ref refs/groups`. This will give you an output like:

      `f582a7915e6d86c8167840da789aa719e65074ee commit \ refs/groups/aa/aaea352bb556868bc6027957d670939b66a953b5` (1)

      `468c8af86d67d808caa28c23f30ea76c417b9815 commit \ refs/groups/dd/dd0f7b0c5b8f949c4957c48dfdf0c5c4de5d84eb`
   2. The first field of on each line is a commit hash. Group Commits have a `group.config` and a `members` file. Check the `group.config` file to see if it's the Administrators group:

      `git show f582a7915e6d86c8167840da789aa719e65074ee:group.config`

      The output should look something like this for the initial Admin group:

      ```
      [group]
          id = 1
          name = Administrators
          description = Gerrit Site Administrators
          ownerGroupUuid = aaea352bb556868bc6027957d670939b66a953b5
          visibleToAll = false
      ```
   3. Awesome! So we've identified that the git ref `refs/groups/aa/aaea352bb556868bc6027957d670939b66a953b5` (2) is the Administrators group, with the latest commit `f582a7915e` (1). We'll keep these in mind for later.
3. Now we'll create a new commit and add it to that ref, the hard way.

   1. We'll create a new `members` file that contains our user. My Gerrit user was 100001, so:

      `echo -e '100000\n100001' > members`
   2. Create a new git blob based on this file (using `-w` to commit it to git's storage)

      `git hash-object -w members`

      This will echo back the SHA1 of the newly created blob. Note that down for later. In my case, it was `3e8cd349203821044ce4a90835b034ff09916b08` (3)

      (you can now delete the `members` file)
   3. Now we need to create a new `git tree` that conforms to Gerrit's group organization. Recall the commit object `1ff7dc0b5` we spied before. Let's have a look at its tree:

      `git ls-tree 1ff7dc0b5813656e5f0b388b7bb94c060f2dbc56`

      Which will output something like:

      `100644 blob 0daf37cff123b35c933c86e314af03130ea984b5  group.config`

      `100644 blob 3e8cd349203821044ce4a90835b034ff09916b08  members`

      So we want to create a new tree but where the `members` file is the one we just created.

      1. We'll keep the same `group.config` as existed in the previous tree (`0daf37c`):

         `git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644 0daf37cff123b35c933c86e314af03130ea984b5 group.config`
      2. Add our new `members` from our blob `3e8cd34` (3) :

         `git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644 3e8cd349203821044ce4a90835b034ff09916b08 members`
      3. And create a new tree from our index:

         `git write-tree`

         Which will echo back the SHA1 of the tree, which we'll keep for later:

         `270bfac6c2c68e24979968083631d97c663e942e` (4)
   4. Now we want to create a new commit object with our newly created tree.

      1. To create commits, Git wants our user info, which it couldn't deduce from my containers, so:

         `git config --global user.email "jlargentaye@example.com"`

         `git config --global user.name "John de Largentaye"`
      2. Then create a new commit object using our tree `270bfac` (4) from previously, as well as the last commit `f582a7915e` (1) for our group. We can either pass the commit message in paragraph chunks through multiple `-m` parameters, or straight in the shell and exit with `^D` (`Ctrl-D`):

         `$ git commit-tree 270bfac6c2c68e24979968083631d97c663e942e -p f582a7915e6d86c8167840da789aa719e65074ee`

         ```
         Update the Administrators group the hard way to add user <me>

         Gee this was "fun"
         ^D
         ```

         This will echo back the SHA of the newly create commit object. In my case:

         `1ff7dc0b5813656e5f0b388b7bb94c060f2dbc56` (5)
   5. Finally, update the Gerrit group ref `refs/groups/aa/aaea35` (2) to point to our new commit `1ff7dc` (5) . We'll reference the previous commit hash `f582a79` (1) to allow git to double-check our work that we're updating the correct ref:

      ```
      git update-ref \
      refs/groups/aa/aaea352bb556868bc6027957d670939b66a953b5 \
      1ff7dc0b5813656e5f0b388b7bb94c060f2dbc56 \
      f582a7915e6d86c8167840da789aa719e65074ee
      ```
4. Restart Gerrit, login as your user, then go to Groups and see if you now see and can edit the Administrators group!

Answer (score 0):

IF you know who the admin user is AND you use LDAP authentication, you can have the LDAP admin change the password for that specific user in LDAP, give it some time to replicate and then you should be able to log in as that user and add yourself to the Administrators group.